# Instalar React Native Vector Icons fallo compilar

Tags: reactjs, ios, react-native, icons, cocoapods

estoy intentando instalar React Native Vector Icons y me salta el siguiente error cuando intento recompilar la app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seguido los siguientes pasos de instalación:

npm i react-native-vector-icons

La carpetas Android>App>build.gradle he añadido la siguiente linea:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

En la carpeta de iOS en Podfile he añadido la siguiente linea:

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

Sin movernos de la carpeta iOS en miApp>Info.plist he añadido el siguiente código:

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key> <array> 
<string>AntDesign.ttf</string> 
<string>Entypo.ttf</string> 
<string>EvilIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>Feather.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string> 
<string>Foundation.ttf</string> 
<string>Ionicons.ttf</string> 
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>Octicons.ttf</string> 
<string>Zocial.ttf</string> </array>
```

Al estar modificando el Podfile he hecho un pod update y un pod install para que se instalasen las dependencias y al intentar compilar de nuevo me ha saltado el error

He estado mirando en esta fuente para volver a hacerlo pero no lo acabo de entender:

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios

Cualquier fuente de ayuda se agradecería ya que ahora mismo no puedo ni compilar,

Un saludo!

---

Update de la pregunta

---

Me he fijado que al hacer el update, supuestamente debería haberse instalado RNVectorIcons solo y se me han instalado otras cosas de Flipper que creo que es lo que debería estar fallando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En flutter me pasa algunas veces. Lo soluciono haciendo un clean del proyecto y eliminando el podfile para volverlo a generar.

Comment: Y cómo se haría eso? Disculpa, es que estoy aprendiendo y hay ciertas cosas que aún no sé como hacerlas

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro pero no crees que te falto este paso?

```
$ react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Además creo que el screen que subiste es del pod update, en realidad con el pod install iba ser suficiente, sería bueno algunos detalles más